# Reducing number of lines / more efficient coding method for field maps

Tags: arcpy, arcmap, csv, field-mapping, code-review

I am looking for ways to reduce the number of lines when making field maps in ArcPy (note, I am using ArcPy with ArcMap 10.6). I cannot seem to figure out a way, and am stuck with a significant amount of lines, though I feel there is a way to do this.

Here is a code snippet:

```
# Define field mapping objects
fm1 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm2 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm3 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm4 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm5 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm6 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm7 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm8 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm9 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm10 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm11 = arcpy.FieldMap()
fm12 = arcpy.FieldMap()

# ***NOTE: 'field1, field2, etc, are actual fields that have different names***
fm1.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field1')
fm2.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field2')
fm3.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field3')
fm4.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field4')
fm5.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field5')
fm6.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field6')
fm7.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field7')
fm8.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field8')
fm9.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field9')
fm10.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field10')
fm11.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field11')
fm12.addInputField(out_dataset, 'field12')

# Add individual field maps into the final field map (fms)
fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()
fms.addFieldMap(fm1)
fms.addFieldMap(fm2)
fms.addFieldMap(fm3)
fms.addFieldMap(fm4)
fms.addFieldMap(fm5)
fms.addFieldMap(fm6)
fms.addFieldMap(fm7)
fms.addFieldMap(fm8)
fms.addFieldMap(fm9)
fms.addFieldMap(fm10)
fms.addFieldMap(fm11)
fms.addFieldMap(fm12)
arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(out_dataset, outLoc, 'Export_Table.csv', '', fms)
```

Can I use some type of for/if statement to reduce the number of lines? If not, is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Please don't make more work for other people by vandalizing your posts. By posting on the Stack Exchange (SE) network, you've granted a non-revocable right, under the [CC BY-SA 4.0 license](https://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/4.0) for SE to distribute that content. By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted. If you want to know more about deleting a post, consider taking a look at: [How does deleting work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5221/295232)?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's erased.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its gibberish.

Comment: The original question was valid, why not restore and lock?  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22228/what-is-a-locked-post

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seeks a code review for which there is the [codereview.se]

Answer (score 5):

Loop through a list of field names perhaps:

```
fields = ['field1', 'field2', 'etc...', 'field12']
# Or
fields = [f.name for f in arcpy.ListFields(out_dataset)]

fms = arcpy.FieldMappings()

for field in fields:
    #Define field mapping objects
    fm = arcpy.FieldMap()
    
    # ***NOTE: 'field1, field2, etc, are actual fields that have different names***
    fm.addInputField(out_dataset, field)

    # Add individual field maps into the final field map (fms)
    fms.addFieldMap(fm)

arcpy.TableToTable_conversion(out_dataset, outLoc, 'Export_Table.csv', '', fms)
```

Comment: Could get slightly smarter again by creating a list comprehension, e.g. `fields = [f'field{i}' for i in range(1, 13)]`. Saves having to type "field" over and over again, and you can adjust the number of fields more easily.

Comment: @alphabetasoup I intentionally did not do that as I assumed field1, field2 were just fake names and the real fields would be something that doesn't follow a 1-n naming convention. Could get a list of fields directly from the featureclass though.

Comment: Right yeah, I didn't see the "note" in OP's code. Demonstrating that would make the answer much more useful, might even redeem the whole question.